# Prove that for Ax = b, the following double perturbed system inequality is satisfied.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, numerical-linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

Prove that if the linear system $Ax = b$ is perturbed in both $A$ and $b$

$$(A + \delta A)(x+ \delta x) = b + \delta b$$

then

$$ \frac{ \| \delta x \| }{ \|x\| } \leq  
\frac{\kappa(A)}{1-\kappa(A)\frac{ \|\delta A\| }{ \|A\| }} 
\left(\frac{ \| \delta A \| }{ \|A\| } + \frac{ \| \delta b \| }{ \|b\| } \right)$$

---

*proof* (Attempt)

First note that in the inequality  above that the denominator term on the right hand side must obey

$$0< 1-\kappa(A)\frac{ \|\delta A\| }{ \|A\| } < 1 \tag{1}$$

because norms, and therefore condition numbers are always positive. The upper bound of $1$ is achieved by the fact that $\|\delta A\| << \|A\|$. And therefore the denominator factor in question, in $(1)$, has multiplicative inverse greater than $1$, implying

$$ \kappa(A) 
\left(\frac{ \| \delta A \| }{ \|A\| } + \frac{ \| \delta b \| }{ \|b\| } \right)<  
\frac{\kappa(A)}{1-\kappa(A)\frac{ \|\delta A\| }{ \|A\| }} 
\left(\frac{ \| \delta A \| }{ \|A\| } + \frac{ \| \delta b \| }{ \|b\| } \right)$$

So for the proof all we must show is

$$ \frac{ \| \delta x \| }{ \|x\| } \leq \kappa(A) 
\left(\frac{ \| \delta A \| }{ \|A\| } + \frac{ \| \delta b \| }{ \|b\| } \right)$$

From the perturbed equation 
\begin{align} 
(A + \delta A)(x+ \delta x) &= b + \delta b \\ 
  Ax +A\delta x + \delta Ax + \delta A\delta x &= b + \delta b \\  
    A\delta x &= \delta b - \delta Ax
\end{align}

The double infinitesimal term is dropped (I don't know why, my book does this quite a bit, how is this justified?). Multiplying the pseudoinverse $A^+$, taking the norm, dividing by the norm of $x$, and using the triangle inequality, we get

\begin{align}
\frac{\|\delta x \|}{\|x\|} \leq \|A^+\|\left(\frac{\|\delta b \|}{\|x\|} + \frac{\|\delta Ax \|}{\|x\|} \right)
\end{align}

Note that from $b = Ax$ we have $\|b\| \leq \|A\|\|x\|$. Using that fact

\begin{align}
\frac{\|\delta x \|}{\|x\|} \leq \|A^+\|\left(\frac{\|\delta b \|}{\|x\|} + \frac{\|\delta Ax \|}{\|x\|} \right) &\leq 
\|A^+\|\left(\frac{\|\delta b \|}{\|b\|}\|A\| + \frac{\|\delta Ax \|}{\|x\|}\right) \\ \\
&= \|A^+\|\left(\frac{\|\delta b \|}{\|b\|}\|A\| + \|\delta A \|\right) \\ \\
&= \kappa(A)\left(\frac{\|\delta b \|}{\|b\|} + \frac{|\delta A \|}{\|A\|}\right) 
_\square
\end{align}

---

The justification for dropping that double infinitesimal is bothering me.

Comment: the reason why we dropping that double infinitesimal , is like we  dropping higher order terms when using taylor expansion approximation

Comment: Yes but we're looking for a bound, so if we drop that term then the right side isn't necessarily a bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof does not make much sense for me because you are trying to prove the inequality
$$\tag{1}
\frac{\|\delta x\|}{\|x\|}\leq\frac{\kappa(A)}{1-\kappa(A)\frac{\|\delta A\|}{\|A\|}}\left(\frac{\|\delta A\|}{\|A\|}+\frac{\|\delta b\|}{\|b\|}\right)
$$
which follows from 
$$\tag{2}
(A+\delta A)(x+\delta x)=b+\delta b
$$
**without** dropping the second order term $\delta A\delta x$ by proving an inequality which might not be true because you dropped the second order term (2).

You do not need to drop anything to prove (1), just need to do a bit more manipulations. See, e.g., [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328816/relative-error-in-solution-when-the-matrix-is-perturbed/2329818#2329818).

Comment: The answer you linked me to is your own answer from last year and in it you *did* drop the higher order term just like I did.

Comment: @Zduff Can you tell me at which step? I can't see it.

Comment: No. Sorry, you are correct.